# How to show the series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$a_{j}> 0\textrm{ for all }j\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}. \, \, \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }a_{j}\in \mathbb{R}.\\
\textrm{Prove that if }\alpha > \frac{1}{2},\textrm{ then }\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{(a_{j})^{\frac{1}{2}}}{j^{\alpha }}\in \mathbb{R}. $$
This is a problem from Real Analysis by Steven G Krantz . I have tried the standard tests suggested in the book, but am not able to proceed. Can I get some hints?

Does convergence hold when$$ \alpha =\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwartz we have for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$:

$\sum_{j=1}^N (a_j)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{j^{\alpha}}\leq(\sum_{j=1}^N a_j)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j^{2\alpha}})^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq (\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j^{2\alpha}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

On the right hand side both series are convergent-the first one because it is given that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j<\infty$, the second one converges because $2\alpha>1$. So we got a bound which does not depend on $N$, hence $\sum_{j=1}^\infty (a_j)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{j^{\alpha}}$ is convergent.

Comment: great thanks. I understand now

Comment: does this hold when alpha = half?

Comment: @tony This is actually an interesting question with $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$. The same method obviously doesn't work here. Maybe there is some counterexample, but a nontrivial one.

Comment: @Mark See my answer for a (not so difficult :)) counterexample !

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, good example.

Answer (score 2):

When $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$, take
$$a_j = \frac{1}{j \ln^2(j)}$$

This is the general term of a (well-known) convergent series, but
$$\sqrt{\frac{a_j}{j}} = \frac{1}{j \ln(j)}$$

is the general term of a (well-known) divergent series.

Comment: thanks @TheSilverDoe  for the help.